# Pie chart.js - display a no data held message

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) Version: 2.8.0 to display a [bar chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) and a [pie chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html).

The non-empty bar and pie charts display as I want.

However, when the bar and pie charts are empty or have zero data to display, **is there a standardised option to display a "No data to display!" message for both the bar and pie charts** that can be shown in place of the empty or zero data.

I've searched google for a plugin and SO for a solution, but the options I've found either don't work at all or don't work for the latest version of chartjs.

Here is my empty pie chart:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('pieChartExample01'), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [
            'Views',
            'Print Requests',
            'PDF Downloads',
            'DOCX Downloads',
        ],
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 0.3)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 0.3)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.3)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 0.6)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 0.6)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.6)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBorderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 1)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 1)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 1)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            borderAlign: 'inner',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
      }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Overall Activity'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="pieChartExample01" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

This is what I would like the empty pie chart to display as (preferably with the labels):

[image]

## UPDATE TO ANSWER - 13th April, 2019

Using the answer provided by Core972, I decided to extrapolate the accepted answer so that the message of choice can be displayed over a bar chart and a pie chart with the data labels displayed rather than just a blank canvas.

Here's the solution that I came up with that works with pie and bar charts.

I haven't tested the other types of charts, but I'm presuming they would work with the same approach.

A few pointers to note:

1. When there is zero data to display, the borders must also be zero, otherwise an annoying border displayed as a single line is displayed. Use a simple if else condition to hide show the borders if necessary.
2. Use an if else condition to display / hide the message. If there is data, hide the message, else display the message if data is zero.
3. I've only tested this approach with Chrome & Firefox and seems to work OK.

I hope that this can help someone! Enjoy!

### PIE CHART WITH DATA LABELS DISPLAYED AND A FLOATING MESSAGE:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('pieChartExample01'), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [
            'Views',
            'Print Requests',
            'PDF Downloads',
            'DOCX Downloads',
        ],
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 0.3)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 0.3)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.3)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 0.6)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 0.6)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.6)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverBorderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(71, 101, 160, 1)',  // #4765a0.
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',  // #000000.
                'rgba(52, 137, 219, 1)',  // #3489db.
                'rgba(179, 179, 179, 1)',  // #b3b3b3.
            ],
            borderAlign: 'inner',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
      }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Overall Activity'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
    <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100px; z-index: 20;">
        <b>No data for you today!</b>
    </div>
    <canvas id="pieChartExample01" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here an example working with chart.js 2.8.0

```
<canvas id="pieChartExample01" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
<div id="no-data">Nothing to display</div>

...
options: {
  title: {
    display: false,
    text: 'Overall Activity'
  },
  animation: {
    onComplete: function(animation) {
      var firstSet = animation.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data,
        dataSum = firstSet.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);

      if (typeof firstSet !== "object" || dataSum === 0) {
        document.getElementById('no-data').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('pieChartExample01').style.display = 'none'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/x7ravowm/)

Answer (score 19):

Use this plugin I slightly modified which checks if each dataset item is zero:

```
<script>
    Chart.plugins.register({
        afterDraw: function(chart) {
            if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.every(item => item === 0)) {
                let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                let width = chart.chart.width;
                let height = chart.chart.height;

                chart.clear();
                ctx.save();
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                ctx.fillText('No data to display', width / 2, height / 2);
                ctx.restore();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

With this, if all dataset items are 0, it will display `No data to display` in place of the chart.

Comment: This is the perfect answer

Comment: Love this answer! Instead of updating the whole Chart class, you can also do it directly on a new single chart instance like `let chart = new Chart(ctx, { plugins: [ { afterDraw: function(chart){...} } ]}`

Comment: Doesn't work in latest version 3.5.1

Answer (score 5):

For those using version 3.x of the library, here's how I did it

```
const plugin = {
    id: 'emptyChart',
    afterDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const { datasets } = chart.data;
        let hasData = false;

        for (let dataset of datasets) {
            //set this condition according to your needs
            if (dataset.data.length > 0 && dataset.data.some(item => item !== 0)) {
                hasData = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasData) {
            //type of ctx is CanvasRenderingContext2D
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D
            //modify it to your liking
            const { chartArea: { left, top, right, bottom }, ctx } = chart;
            const centerX = (left + right) / 2;
            const centerY = (top + bottom) / 2;

            chart.clear();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.fillText('No data to display', centerX, centerY);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
};
```

And just use the above like so:

```
const chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [plugin]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## For `React` ([react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2))

Use this plugin

```
const plugins = [
  {
    afterDraw: function (chart) {
      console.log(chart);
      if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length < 1) {
        let ctx = chart.ctx;
        let width = chart.width;
        let height = chart.height;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("No data to display", width / 2, height / 2);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    },
  },
];
```

Use this plugin

```
<Line height={120} data={props.data} options={options} plugins={plugins} />
<Pie height={320} width={500} data={props.data} options={options} plugins={plugins} />
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to set some data in data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
It's imposible to display pie graph without any data i try to change only data and all it's good.

```
...
data: [2, 3, 4, 5]
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/myeLq37j/

Comment: You have misread the question! When there is no data to display, I want a message displayed.